# Getting form submitted date

Tags: forms, datetime

I have a date picker in my form, when user hits submit button, the date which entered in date field is displaying in list view. But I want to display the date the form submitted also.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Views module you can add this field:

Content: Updated date, The date the content was last updated.